# CSS [attribute^=value] selector for class that doenst appear first?

Tags: css

I need to use the attribute and value CSS selector to target a class as it's generated and will change. This works fine:

```
[class^="class1"] {
  background: gold
}

<p class="class1-gdsgdfgsgd">Hi</p>
```

However in reality the class that I need to target doesn't come first. Is there a way to target `class1-ANYTHING` in this situation?

```
<p class="classA-fuiiiid classB-djfksdjf <!-- Maybe other classes here --> class1-dfgsfggfd">Hi</p>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were there already, you just have to use the `regex` anywhere(*) for this:

> Replace `^` to `*`:

```css
[class*='class1'] {
    color: red;  
    font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<p class="classA-fuiiiid classB-djfksdjf class1-dfgsfggfd">Hi</p>
```